# SQL relationship to enforce rule that a table can only reference rows of another table with the same foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have a simple database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Report
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ReportText
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Content varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    FK_ReportID int NOT NULL,
    FK_FontID int NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Font
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    FK_ReportID int NOT NULL
)
```

In plain English:

- A `Report` contains multiple `ReportText` rows
- Each `ReportText` has a `Font`
- Each `Font` is restricted to a `Report`

  - i.e. The ReportTexts for ReportA cannot use any of the Fonts for ReportB

I can enforce everything with simple foreign keys, except that last requirement. I can have:

- a foreign key from `Report.ID` to `ReportText.FK_ReportID`
- a foreign key from `Report.ID` to `Font.FK_ReportID`

...but I need a third relationship that will prevent a `ReportText` from selecting a `Font` for a report ID different from its own `FK_ReportID`.

Is this possible or is there a problem with my schema?

Comment: Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `FK_FontID`, assuming the same font is not used more than once for the same report.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm not sure I understand how that will help. My understanding is that  that will prevent me from using a `Font` more than once entirely and it will still permit me to reference `Font`s for a report other than the one referenced by `ReportText.FK_ReportID`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can create a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to implement that, ms docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure)

Comment: "Each Font is restricted to a Report" - I understood this to mean you don't want a font to be used more than once entirely (i.e. on a different report). It seems to me "permit me to reference Fonts for a report other than the one referenced by ReportText.FK_ReportID" is contradictory but it's probably just my misunderstanding.

Comment: I've just realized that a simple `CHECK CONSTRAINT` won't help you as it works at row level (it uses only data in the current row), therefore we need to add something more, a scalar function that returns to be called that will check if that FontID is used in any other Report.
Or you can use a trigger... but I suggest you avoid triggers whenever possible.

Comment: @DanGuzman No, maybe my writing wasn't clear but a font can be used any number of times but only within the report referenced by its `FK_ReportID`, i.e. there can be multiple `ReportText` rows that reference each font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use declarative constraints with your existing model to limit a font to a single report and only that report. This can be accomplished by adding a composite key unique constraint on the `Font` table `ID` and `FK_ReportID` columns and reference the alternate key with a foreign key constraint on the `ReportText` table.

Example DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Report
(
    ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Report PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Font
(
    ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Font PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    FK_ReportID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Font_Report FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Report(ID),
    CONSTRAINT AK_Font_ID_FK_ReportID UNIQUE(ID, FK_ReportID)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ReportText
(
    ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_ReportText PRIMARY KEY,
    Content varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    FK_ReportID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_ReportText_Report FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Report(ID),
    FK_FontID int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ReportText_Font FOREIGN KEY (FK_FontID, FK_ReportID) REFERENCES dbo.Font(ID, FK_ReportID),
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Report VALUES(1,'Report1');
INSERT INTO dbo.Report VALUES(2,'Report2');

INSERT INTO dbo.Font VALUES(1,'Font1',1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Font VALUES(2,'Font2',1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Font VALUES(3,'Font3',2);

INSERT INTO dbo.ReportText VALUES(1,'content1',1,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.ReportText VALUES(2,'content2',1,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.ReportText VALUES(3,'content3',1,2);
INSERT INTO dbo.ReportText VALUES(4,'content1',2,3);

--this fails because font 3 is not valid for report 1
INSERT INTO dbo.ReportText VALUES(5,'content4',1,3);
--this fails because font 1 is not valid for report 2
INSERT INTO dbo.ReportText VALUES(5,'content2',2,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Check Constraint with aid from a function should be something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckFontUsage (@ReportID int, @FontID int)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AlreadyUsed bit;
    SELECT @AlreadyUsed = IIF(COUNT(*) > 0,1,0) FROM dbo.ReportText WHERE FK_ReportID <> @ReportID AND FK_FontID = @FontID

    RETURN(@AlreadyUsed);
END

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ReportText 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_YourConstrName CHECK (dbo.CheckFontUsage(FK_ReportID,FK_FontID) = 0)
GO
```

Choose meaningful names for both the constraint and function

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do this without the need for a function:

```
/* For testing we may want to drop these
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ReportText;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FontsReports
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Reports;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Fonts;
*/

CREATE TABLE Reports (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Fonts (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(100))

CREATE TABLE FontsReports (FontID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Fonts(ID), 
                           ReportID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Reports(ID));
CREATE TABLE ReportText (ID INT IDENTITY, Content NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, ReportID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Reports(ID), 
                                                                          FontID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Fonts(ID));
INSERT INTO Reports (Name) VALUES 
('Allow Font one'),('Allow Font two'),('Allow font one and two');

INSERT INTO Fonts (NAME) VALUES 
('Font one'),('Font two'),('Font three');

INSERT INTO FontsReports (FontID, ReportID) VALUES
(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3);

ALTER TABLE FontsReports ADD PRIMARY KEY(FontID, ReportID)

ALTER TABLE FontsReports WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT AllowedFontAndReport 
FOREIGN KEY(FontID)   REFERENCES Fonts(ID), 
FOREIGN KEY(ReportID) REFERENCES Reports(ID)

ALTER TABLE ReportText WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT AllowedFontReport 
FOREIGN KEY(FontID, ReportID) REFERENCES FontsReports (FontID, ReportID)

INSERT INTO ReportText (Content, ReportID, FontID) VALUES 
('Something that works.', 1, 1)

INSERT INTO ReportText (Content, ReportID, FontID) VALUES 
('Something that fails', 2, 1)
```

This should create the tables and add constraints to them. It does utilize a lookup to force the composite key and make it referenceable.

I'm not sure it's a better answer than the one previously posted, but it was neat to write.

Comment: Thanks, this likely will work but I think it will come at the cost of having to alter the schema to have that 4th linking table `FontsReports` that you had added. I'd prefer to use the scalar function and keep the schema as simple as possible.

Comment: I find this design clean, but it still doesn't limit a specific font to one report, as you could just add the allowed combo to the `FontsReports` table... and you are back to square one.
But, you can actually enforce it by setting a UNIQUE constraint on `FontsReports` col `FontID`.

Comment: The uniqueness is enforced by the values in the lookup. If your pair is not present it can't be used. I liked this as it made it easy to allow/deny specific pairings by inserting/deleting rows. It does add a table to the schema, though.